# ngxs spread operator when copying array not working

Tags: angular, ngxs

I try to copy just the values of an array property within my state, but I do not get it to work as expected. The state should be updated when the `patchState` method is called and not without it. What am I doing wrong?

```
@Action(PostAttachment)
  postAttachment(ctx: StateContext<EditEntityStateModel>, { preview, selectedEntityId }: PostAttachment) {
    ctx.patchState({ currentlyUploading: true });
    const previews = [...ctx.getState().previews.data];
    console.log(previews);
    const updatedData = previews.map(previewFromMapping => {
      if (previewFromMapping.filename === preview.filename) {
        previewFromMapping.status = 'uploading';
      }
      return singleData;
    })
    console.log('new', updatedData);
    ctx.patchState({ previews: { ...ctx.getState().previews, data: updatedData }});
  }
```

So the second and the first `console.log()` are the same, but they should not. Both of them show the exact same output. So I guess, I accidentally copy the state reference for that given array, not the values itself. **BUT WHY?**

Comment: Where is the value `singleData` being defined?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not clear on what you are missing or wanting to happen, but I have cleaned up your code a bit and made my best guess at what you intended to happen (I'll update the answer if more details are provided):

```js
// START: TYPINGS 
class PreviewData {
  filename: string
}

class Preview {
  data: PreviewData[]
}

class EditEntityStateModel {
  previews: Preview;
  currentlyUploading: boolean;
}
// END: TYPINGS 

// START: ACTIONS 
class PostAttachment {
  static type = '[Previews] post attachment'
  constructor(public previewData: PreviewData, public selectedEntityId) {
  }
}
// END: ACTIONS
 
// START: STATE
  @Action(PostAttachment)
  postAttachment(ctx: StateContext<EditEntityStateModel>, { previewData }: PostAttachment) {
    const state = ctx.getState();
    const previewsData: PreviewData[] = [...state.previews.data];
    console.log(previewsData);
    const updatedData = previewsData.map(data => data.filename === previewData.filename ? {...data, status: 'uploading'} : data)
    // This should be a list of same length and data as previewsData, but with items with matching filename having a status of 'uploading'
    console.log('new', updatedData);
    ctx.patchState({ currentlyUploading: true, previews: { ...state.previews, data: updatedData }});
  }
 // END: STATE


  // Given a starting state:

  //  {
  //    previews: {
  //      data: [{
  //        filename: 'Hello',
  //        status: 'awaitingUpload'
  //      }, {
  //        filename: 'Goodbye',
  //        status: 'awaitingUpload'
  //      }]
  //    },
  //    currentlyUploading: false
  //  }

  // Dispatch action:

  // this.store.dispatch(new PostAttachment({ filename: 'Hello' });

  // Should result in state of: 

  //  {
  //    previews: {
  //      data: [{
  //        filename: 'Hello',
  //        status: 'uploading'
  //      }, {
  //        filename: 'Goodbye',
  //        status: 'awaitingUpload'
  //      }]
  //    },
  //    currentlyUploading: true
  //  }
```